App compatibility with sky device WHY ? Is possible to make it compatible without having to change device
Door dash driver App is not compatible with sky device D63 android 13. Playstore say it should be android 6+>.Why and can it be made compatible without changing device.

For reference a Sky Device D63 is a Android Go device with only 2 GB of RAM. Given that Door Dash has a end-user and driver app, linking to the one with the problem would be useful for future readers.

As Android Go disables "draw over other apps" perhaps might be useful: Enable Display Over Other Apps Android 10-11 Go Edition (Nokia 1.4) when "feature is disabled because it slows down the phone"? but be prepared for crashing if you have too many things running.

I'll try that thank you
